# Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Getting that error in console when trying to get data from a API. Anybody have this issue before?

```
var url = "https://api.website.com/get/?type=events&lat=" + localStorage.getItem('latitude')
+ "&lng=" + localStorage.getItem('longitude') + "&distance=50";

$http({
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})

$http.get(url).success(function (events) {
    $scope.events = events;
});
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
at Gb (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:114:238)
at s (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:65:249)
at new EventsController (http://localhost:38772/www/js/angular.js:4:5)
at d (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:30:452)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:31:80)
at http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:61:486
at http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:49:14
at q (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:7:380)
at E (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:48:382)
at f (http://localhost:38772/www/js/plugins/angular.min.js:42:399)
```

Comment: is the value in `url` set properly? (`http(s)://example.com`)

Comment: url is posted above now

Comment: I faced this problem when **URL** parameter is undefined.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**You're issuing a malformed $http request.**

You are not supposed to set your headers in a separate call to `$http`. Call to `$http()` will actually issue the request, but since you configured it with just the header (no url or method), it throws that error at you (as expected).

If you want to set your header you'll want to do that by passing a custom config object as a second parameter to your `$http.get()` call:

```
$http.get(url, {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }
}).success(function (events) {
  $scope.events = events;
});
```

Comment: I'm getting 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' error now. Any clue on this one?

Comment: You're issuing request to a different origin/domain. Google "angular cors".

Comment: I got this error because I pasted some $.post code to use for $.delete and $.delete (quite appropriately) does not have the 2nd param that $.post does (the data)

Answer (score 27):

This error occurs when something goes wrong in request, for ex. if you set url as undefined, invalid method, or invalid content type, anything wrong with request object will throw this error.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. In my case it was due to fetching a react environment variable. I didn't restart server after adding that environment variable

Comment: You are right. URL was undefined in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same Issue calling an API from react.
After checking my code I saw the endpoint from the environment file could not be found which led to the error.

All I did to fix it was to stop and restart the react app

Answer (score 1):

In vue 2 project if you're using `axios` and facing this error then try this solution.

- Install `vue-axios` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios
- Use `vue-axios` in this way to remove **protocol error**
- `import Vue from 'vue'`
- `import axios from 'axios'`
- `import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'` //this line is important to remove **'protocol' ERROR**
- `Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me was that I had a file in the project that I called AXIOS.JS and I imported from there into other files and it really confused the system, therefore it is forbidden to give the file names of modules in the project