# AngularJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have changed the $http > URL parameter inside my AngularJS app from

```
       $http({ method:'POST',
                   url:'http://localhost/api/clients.php'
       }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                     deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
                     deferred.reject(status);
       });
```

to

```
       $http({ method:'POST',
                   url: ConfigService.Urls.Clients
       }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                     deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
                     deferred.reject(status);
       });
```

where ConfigService is as follows:

```
Urls: {},
loadUrls: function(){
   Urls.Clients = 'http://localhost/api/clients.php';
}
```

Of course I call loadUrls before loading controller through .Resolve so I am 100% sure Urls.Clients is not null.

After I did this change I started getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at urlIsSameOrigin (http://localhost/myapp/app/lib/angular/angular.js:13710:17)
    at $http (http://localhost/myapp/app/lib/angular/angular.js:7508:23)
```

What is so confusing is that the application works just fine, except for that error I am getting...can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? and why I am getting this error if the application is already working without a problem.

Comment: Does this help at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347542/cannot-read-property-protocol-of-undefined

Comment: @drew_w No, as it is a different case, here I am don't split the header

Comment: Can you put in the full $http call?

Comment: Basically the only thing I see here is that the `Urls.Clients` must somehow be `undefined`. Sorry to keep asking questions - but, where is `loadUrls()` called at? I don't see that in your code. Also, if you just set the URLS in the service instead of putting it in a function, does that work better?

Comment: @drew_w ConfigService is a service and that's where the url is loaded then I inject this service in services / controllers whenever needed. Having said so, loadUrls are loaded on first controller (home page) load using route provider resolve

Comment: @drew_w yes if I set the url directly in service it shows no error, but then I have to go over all urls in case url is changed

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly an issue with order. The `loadUrls` isn't getting called until after the `$http` call is run for the first time. This could be because controllers aren't necessarily loaded in the order you expect - you can't count on the route provider opening and starting up your home controller before it runs other controllers - that is just going to depend on how things are setup. Given the amount of code you have provided here its hard to say what exactly is going wrong as far as order.

That in mind you have a few general options that will fix this:

- Always call `loadUrls()` before you run a `$http` request. This isn't elegant but it will fix the issue
- Wrap all of your `$http` calls and call `loadUrls()` in that wrapper. This is slightly better than the previous because if you need to change `loadUrls()` or make sure it is called only once you can implement that logic later.
- You already observed this, but you can change your initialization to be directly in the service rather than in a routine provided by the service. This will fix the issue although it may leave you in a place where you have to update the service every time the url's change.
- Live with the error, knowing that when the controller loads it will instantiate and get the correct data at that point in time. I don't often love solutions like this because it could cause errors later that are hard to trace but if you don't like any of the previous options this could technically be ok.
- Use an app configuration, which is executed when the application loads (note that not all resources are initialized and injection is not allowed). An example [from the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

  ```
  angular.module('myModule', []).
    config(function(injectables) {
        // provider-injector
        // This is an example of config block.
        // You can have as many of these as you want.
        // You can only inject Providers (not instances)
        // into config blocks.
    }).
  ```

  You can use this or a run block to initialize what you want

I'm sure there are other options as well depending on how your code is structured but hopefully this at least gets you started. Best of luck!

Comment: You are correct, what happens is that the $http call returns a promise, but the code causing the error run before the promise is fulfilled. Is there a way I can call the $http on application startup and prevent the app from running if the promise fails?

Comment: @MChan I added another option which will probably do what you are looking for here. Because angular itself is initializing you can't do anything, but `run` or `config` should probably get you further along.

Comment: I can't inject my service in config, thus it won't help much

Comment: @MChan did you try `.run`?

Comment: .run won't make any difference, I mean the same problem exist as even if the promise failed, it will still continue running code in run section

Comment: The only way it worked was by Always call loadUrls() before you run a $http request....but that is not good as I will have to replicate same code at least 20 times on each $http call :(

Answer (score -2):

I had this same problem, and I fixed it by changing this:

```
    var logoutURL = URL + '/logout';
    function sendLogoutHttp(){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: logoutURL,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    }
```

to this

```
    function sendLogoutHttp(){
        var logoutURL = URL + '/logout';
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: logoutURL,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    }
```