# TypeError: Cannot read property of "content" of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React app route returns an error when the page is reloaded in the browser.

My landing page has a blog section with buttons that link to a page with the full list of blog articles and another set of pages that link to full articles for each blog entry. I am bringing in the blog entries from WordPress via its API and using Context to manage state and share data with my components. I am using React Router to navigate from the landing page to both the list of articles and each full article. The route structure from the landing page: "/articles/:postId".

I have been able to display individual full articles when pressing a "read more" button. However, when I reload the browser on the page with the full article, I get an error which matches the title of my post. Looking at the console, I see the following errors:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"

"index.js:1446 The above error occurred in the  component:
    in Article (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:19)
    in Switch (at App.js:16)
    in Provider (at App.js:15)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:14)
    in App (at src"

I haven't tried anything to fix it as I am not sure what is the source of this particular error. I am not even able to go backward in my browser to clear it. I have to go back to my landing page and reload the browser to clear the issue.

Context.js:

```
const Context = React.createContext();

export class Provider extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            content: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('url')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            content: data
        }));
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

Route setup:

```
 return (
    <Router>
      <Provider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/articleList/" exact component={ArticleList}/>
          <Route path={`/articleList/:articleId`} component={Article}/>
        </Switch>
      </Provider>
    </Router>
);
```

Article component code:

```
const Article = ({match}) => {
return(
  <Consumer>
    {value => {
      const [...articles] = value.content;

      const res = articles.find(article=> article.id === parseInt(match.params.articleId))

      return(
          <ArticleBody content={res.content.rendered}/>
      )

    }}
  </Consumer>
)
}
```

I am looking to be able to reload pages without seeing these errors.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347542/cannot-read-property-protocol-of-undefined

Comment: `"index.js:1446 The above error occurred in the component: in Article` , can you show the `Article` component code? or better provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I added the relevant Article component code. See above

Comment: the `res` is not found that's why you have `content of undefined` error, which means  article id match is not found. I suggest you debug the `article=> { debugger; return article.id === parseInt(match.params.articleId)}` and check first if the types of `id`'s match before comparing.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I don't understand why it finds that article Id successfully when I click on 'read more' but not when I reload the browser while viewing the article. I attempted the debugger but I am not seeing anything new in terms of errors or clues.

Comment: you dont have ``const [...articles] = value.content`` yet on first load - try 
``const [...articles] = value ? value.content : []`` or even better ``const articles = value ? [...value.content] : []``

Comment: @fard i see what you are suggesting. I tried that but it did not work. I looked in the console as I load the page from the link and then reloaded the browser and I go from a value of more than 0 to 0 on the reload.

Comment: @martinpsz could you provide me working example?

Comment: @fard and others, I have been giving thought to my issue and am looking for feedback on both ideas:

Idea 1: I don't currently have an event listener attached to the button that leads to a full article. I am thinking of adding an onclick that grabs the ID of the article and uses that to set state in the article component.

Idea 2: Since I have been able to get away with not having an event handler on the "read more" button, another thought comes to mind. Can I just use "componentwillupdate" to update the state since I do not need the entirety of my context...just one of the entries via ID?